# Azure SAS | Error | Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature

Tags: azure, azure-sas

I have got details to send data to Azure SAS.

Storage Account Name: acountname123
Blob Container Name - containername123

SAS URI:
https://acountname123.blob.core.windows.net/containername123?sv=2019-12-12&si=xxinboundpolicy&sr=c&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I tried to call this from soapui however its giving error related to authorization header.
Can you pl help me with what I need to pass in authorization header.

I followed below links
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json

[image: SOAP UI]

Thanks
Yatan

Comment: How did you create the SAS URI?

Comment: I got this from other team, I am just trying to create connectivity and want to send file.

Comment: Looks like there's an issue with the SAS URL itself. Please reach out to the team who gave you this and ask them to give you correct SAS URL.